# Error when install gem nokogiri on openSuse - Could not create Makefile and unable locate mkmf.log

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I want to install gem nokogiri on my openSuse Leap 42.1 system. And I have installed the libxml2-devel and libxslt-devel, due to following commands:

[show libxml2-devel and libxslt-devel installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KABtB.jpg) The sign 'i' indicates the package installed.

And when I command "sudo gem install nokogiri", it outputs the following messages:

[the output of 'sudo gem install nokogiri'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaz5i.jpg)

I guess the details is in the 'mkmf.log', but I don't konw where it is.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

I am running opensuse thumbelweed and I had to first install the libs

`sudo zypper in libxml2-devel libxslt-devel`

And then pass the use system libraries to the gem install:

`gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7.1' -- --use-system-libraries`

Answer (score 0):

You should install zlib. It will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No one person answer my question. I answer it by myself. I should first find the file mkmf.log to check the details. I do not know where it is; however, it actually exists in the nokogiri gem directory, which found by the command

```
cd /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7
find -name mkmf.log
```

After I have passed the requiments in the mkmf.log file, I should also view the error log in the console, which give me another prompts.

In general, I installed libxml2-devel, libxslt-devel, perl-Text-Iconv, and git, before I could successfully installed nokogiri gem.